# make - stripping unused files

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

In my current project, more than 200MB C files are present. While making targets I can able to see only < 100MB is used to create a binary. How, to identify what are the files are not touched while creating targets. So, that we can strip it off and make the codebase more sleek.

How, to identify the list of files created for target while compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is to use one of [the methods Linux offers for monitoring file system access](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/linux-file-access-monitoring):

1. [inotifywait](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki)
2. [kfsmd](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/124903)
3. [loggerfs](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/)
4. [auditd / auditctl / ausearch](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-security_sd_draft/cha.audit.setup.html)

You could also run the `make` command with [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) (`strace -f make`) and parse the output for `open()` calls.
That is what I used to do in the past.

Take your pick.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably:

1. `make clean`
2. `make 2>out` to capture the full log of the build to a file
3. `grep`the `out` file for `gcc` invocations
4. Filter out the filenames from the `gcc` invocations
5. Build a sorted list of those filenames
6. Build a sorted list of filenames in the project.
7. Compare the two.

Or something like that. Shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to open the (autogenerated) dependency files for you executables and shared libraries. They are going to contain `.o` as prerequisites, which normally correspond to `.c`.

This works best for non-recursive make build systems with complete dependency trees.

Answer (score 0):

If your `make` is GNU `make`, as seems likely, you could consider 
variations on the following approach. (For simplicity I'll assume that the only
source files of interest are `.c` files.)

Say we have `Makefile` in directory `dir` that makes some default
target and possibly others, including intermediate targets.

You can use another makefile, say, `unused_srcs.mk` that you `include` in
`Makefile`, such that in `dir` you can run:

```
make unused_srcs
```

which will display a list of all the source files in `dir` that don't
contribute to the default target. Or run:

```
make unused_srcs target=TARG
```

for some target `TARG`, and get a list of all the source files in `dir` that
don't contribute to `TARG`.

This assumes that `Makefile` has a `clean` target, or maybe several
variants of `clean[-???]`, that can suitably clean the default target or
any target you might be interested in, and that you don't mind
a suitable `clean[-???]` being invoked for the `unused_srcs` target.

For example, in `dir` we have:

**main.c**

```
extern void boo(void);

int main(void)
{
    boo();
    return 0;
}
```

**boo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void boo(void)
{
    puts("Boo!");
}
```

**noop.c**

```
void noop(void){}
```

**Makefile**

```
.phony: all clean

all: boo

objs = main.o boo.o

boo: $(objs)
    gcc -o $@ $^

clean-obj:
    rm -f *.o

clean: clean-obj
    rm -f boo

# include /some/standard/place/unused_srcs.mk
include unused_srcs.mk
```

And in some standard place which, for simplicity, we'll assume is again `dir`,
we have:

**unused_srcs.mk**

```
.phony: unused_srcs

ifndef $(target)
target = all
endif

ifndef $(cleaner)
cleaner = clean
endif

all_srcs = $(wildcard *.c)
used_srcs = $(filter %.c,$(shell ($(MAKE) $(cleaner) && $(MAKE) -n -d $(target)) \
    | grep -e 'Considering target file' | sed -e "s/[\`\']//g" -e "s/\.$$//g" -))
unused_srcs = $(filter-out $(used_srcs),$(all_srcs))

unused_srcs:
    @echo $(unused_srcs)
```

In this project:-

- `noop.c` is unused by `boo` (it is completely superfluous)
- `noop.c` and `main.c` are unused by `boo.o`
- `noop.c` and `boo.c` are unused by `main.o`

And we can discover such facts with `make unused_srcs` commands:

```
$ make unused_srcs
noop.c
$ make unused_srcs target=boo
noop.c
$ make unused_srcs target=boo.o
main.c noop.c
$ make unused_srcs cleaner=clean-obj target=boo.o
main.c noop.c
$ make unused_srcs target=main.o
boo.c noop.c
$ make unused_srcs target=clean
boo.c main.c noop.c
```

Clearly all the heavy-lifting is done in the evaluation of `$(used_srcs)`
and `$(unused_srcs)` in `unused_srcs.mk`, and mostly the former.

The evaluation of `$(used_srcs)` exploits GNU `make`'s `-d` option, which
generates fulsome debugging info, together with the fact that any source
file that *does* contribute to the chosen TARG must itself be considered
a potential target when TARG is made.

Together, these things mean that if we clean TARG and then run `make -n -d TARG`
the output will be the debugging info of a dry-run (`-n`) of `make TARG`,
and in this output a line like:

> Considering target file `FILE.c'.

will appear for each `.c` file `FILE.c` that contributes to `TARG`, and
for no other `.c` files that may be present.

The evaluation of `$(used_srcs)` generates that debugging info and filters
it to extract the names of the `.c` files.

The evaluating of  `$(unused_srcs)` then just weeds out the `$(used_srcs)`
from the list of all the `.c` files there are.